# How to access Python help on [Py]Spark's "toDF"?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to spin up on Python and PySpark.  I followed [this page](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/install-pyspark-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook/?expand_article=1) on installing and checking PySpark in Anaconda on Windows.  The following checking code works:

```
>>> import findspark
>>> findspark.init()
>>> findspark.find()
'C:\\Users\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\lib\\site-packages\\pyspark'

>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkExamples.com').getOrCreate()
>>> data = [("Java","20000"), ("Python","100000"), ("Scala","3000")]
>>> columns = ["language","users_count"]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
>>> df.show()
+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    Java|      20000|
|  Python|     100000|
|   Scala|       3000|
+--------+-----------+
```

I am tried accessing the online help for the methods `createDataFrame` and `toDF`.  Getting help on `createDataFrame` was straighforward: `help(spark.createDataFrame)`.

I haven't been able to access the online help for `toDF`:

```
>>> help(spark.toDF)
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'toDF'

>>> help(DataFrame.toDF)
NameError: name 'DataFrame' is not defined

>>> help(spark.DataFrame.toDF)
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

>>> help(DataFrame)
NameError: name 'DataFrame' is not defined

>>> help(spark.DataFrame)
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

**(1) How is the documentation accessed?**

**(2) Is there a scheme for accessing the help that one can infer based on the checking code above?**

Comment: Command line `help` is for the `PySpark` command line documentation access and not for Python Spark API. To see Spark API related help check official documentation here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html and for command line help try `>>> --help`

Comment: @Vikramsinh Shinde: I'm confused.  The cited page says that PySpark *is* a Python API into Spark.  Can you please clarify?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the `DataFrame` class from `pyspark.sql`

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
>>> help(DataFrame.toDF)
"""
Help on function toDF in module pyspark.sql.dataframe:

toDF(self, *cols)
    Returns a new class:`DataFrame` that with new specified column names

    :param cols: list of new column names (string)

    >>> df.toDF('f1', 'f2').collect()
    [Row(f1=2, f2='Alice'), Row(f1=5, f2='Bob')]
"""
```

Comment: Thank you, *enamya*. To understand your answer, I read up on packages, modules, and different import syntaxes. I then found the `pyspark` package and `sql` subpackage in `sys.path`. The module `dataframe.py` therein contains the `toDF` method. I confirmed that the file was correct using `import inspect; inspect.getfile(DataFrame)`, which yields `C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py`.

Comment: The filename stem `dataframe`, however, does not match the *case* of name of the imported module `DataFrame`. My web searching indicates that Python is case sensitive. Curiously `dataframe.py` contains a `DataFrame` *class* for which the `toDF` method is defined. My understanding is that `from pyspark.sql import DataFrame` *should* instead import the subpackage module `pyspark/sql/module.py` (i.e., `from pyspark.sql import dataframe`) and that the `DataFrame` class should then be prefixed with the module name, i.e., `help(dataframe.DataFrame.toDF)`.

Comment: How is it possible that I can directly import the `DataFrame` class without mentioning the module name `dataframe`, and that I can then directly access class `DataFrame` without the module name `dataframe` as a prefix?

Comment: I wonder if the explanation is that `pyspark/sql/__init__.py` contains the initialization `from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame, ...`. It doesn't fully explain why `from pyspark.sql import DataFrame` works. The initialization puts `DataFrame` in the current namespace, but it doesn't make `DataFrame` into a module within the `pysppark.sql` subpackage.