# Importing a class from module into current namespace makes the class look a module within a subpackage

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I'm spinning up on both Python and PySpark.  I followed [this page](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/install-pyspark-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook/?expand_article=1) on installing PySpark in Anaconda on Windows.  I tried to get online help on a `DataFrame` class and its `toDF` method.  From [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761870/2153235), the required import (and subsequent help commands) are:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame # User import command
help(DataFrame)
help(DataFrame.toDF)
```

The code works, but I don't understand why, even after reading extensively on packages, modules, and initialization (e.g., [here](https://realpython.com/lessons/package-initialization), [here](https://realpython.com/python-import), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144872)).

The `DataFrame` class is defined in package `pyspark`, subpackage `sql`, module file `dataframe.py`.  File `pyspark/sql/__init__.py` contains initialization

```
# __init__.py import command
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame, DataFrameNaFunctions, DataFrameStatFunctions
```

I see how this `__init__.py import command` puts the `DataFrame` class in the current namespace.  In order for the `User import command` at the top to run, however, `DataFrame` must appear like a module in the `pyspark.sql` subpackage.  I don't see how the `__init__.py import command` accomplishes this.

Can someone explain, point to a key passage in one of my cited resources, and/or refer me to other information?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the answer is given
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/2153235):
"When a regular package is imported, this
__init__.py file is implicitly executed, and the
objects it defines are bound to names in the
package’s namespace".  So if
`pyspark/sq/__init__.py` contains:

```
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame, etc.
```

then `DataFrame` is a name that exists in the
`pyspark.sql` namespace.  Hence it makes perfect
sense to import it from there via

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
```

Assuming that the above is issued from a REPL,
this puts `DataFrame` in the namespace of the
REPL.

Contrary to what I said in the question, the
`__init__.py` does *not* import DataFrame into the
"current" namespace (the REPL namespace in the
scenario here).  This was such a mistake that I
thought of deleting the question. However, other
newbies might also mistakenly think that
`__init__.py` files (or even imported module
`*.py` files) run in the context of the "current"
namespace, similar to sourcing a script from a
shell.

My question also says that:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
```

implies that `DataFrame` appears like a *module*
in the `pyspark.sql` subpackage.  Having read a
lot more, I see that this is not true.  The
`import` command imports not just *modules*, but
also classes and in fact any object defined within
the module's `*.py` file (see
[here](https://medium.com/code-85/a-beginners-guide-to-importing-in-python-bb3adbbacc2b)).